# ListBox with WrapPanel - Remove item / arrow key navigation

Tags: wpf, listbox, navigation, wrappanel, arrow-keys

I have a strange problem regarding my listbox / wrappanel arrow navigation.

My Listbox :

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
     SelectedIndex="{Binding MainIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentFeed, Mode=TwoWay}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFeedList}" 
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Panel}" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Width="168">
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,7,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image , Converter={StaticResource ByteArraytoImageSource}}" Width="150" Height="213" ></Image>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0"  Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFontFamily}" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The render :
[image: Render of Listbox]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://muby53.free.fr/render.png))</sub>

The render is great No problem ! ;)

As you can see it's a list of wallpaper retrieved from RSS.

I have bind a shortcut to make one item readed and then it's removed from the ObservableCollection :

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="D" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding ReadCmd}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

In My View Model :

```
ObservableCollection<Feed> CurrentFeedList { get; set; }
private Feed _currentFeed;
public Feed CurrentFeed
{
    get { return _currentFeed; }
    set
    {
        _currentFeed = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentFeed");
    }
}
public ICommand ReadCmd { get; set; }
public int MainIndex { get; set; }
```

My ReadCmd is a RelayCommand that call "ReadAction" method.

At the beginning I simply remove the item from the ObservableCollection, but I want to type Ctrl+D  twice to read 2 item.

So I decided to get the index of the listbox and select back the same index after removing one.

```
private void ReadAction()
{
    int previousIndex = MainIndex;

    if (previousIndex == CurrentFeedList.Count - 1)
        previousIndex -= 1;

    CurrentFeedList.Remove(CurrentFeed);

    CurrentFeed = CurrentFeedList[previousIndex];
}
```

It's work as I wanted, but one problem remain and I can't solve it.

**When I push Ctrl+D the SelectedItem is remove and the next item become Selected. But then when I use the arrow key navigation to navigate over the list, it jump each time to the first item of the list.**

I hope it's enough clear.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the fact that when you are removing the items using the `KeyBinding`, `ListBox` loses the focus and hence pressing the arrow keys after that places focus on first item of the `ListBox`.

So in order to make your arrow keys work from the selected item you will also have to set the focus on Selected Item of the `Listbox`.

There are couple of ways of doing this, e.g using attached behavior to set the focus on the `ListBoxItem`. Simplest would be to capture the `SelectionChanged` event of your ListBox and in the handler set the focus on the currently selected item like below:

```
    private void MyListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var item =  (ListBoxItem)MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListBox.SelectedItem);

       if(item !=null)
          item.Focus();
    }
```